# Disable Shipping fee calculation on different radio button WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Can javascript in WordPress WooCommerce disable the calculation of shipping fee?

Here's my code that I am using and screenshot of the website. Because in the third or last radio button is for "Pick-up" only it should remove the calculation of the shipping fee incoming from WooCommerce/WordPress.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DafGa.jpg)

Is there anyone has a good solution for this? Thanks!

```
        $('#shipToCheckout').click(function() {
        var radioValue = $("input[name='check-ship']:checked"). val();
        var default_id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var new_id = parseInt(default_id)+1;
        if(radioValue == ""){
            $(".paymentoption").html('');
            $(".paymentoption").html('enter or select address');
        }

        var errMsg = '';
        if(radioValue == '1'){
            $("#pickup_date_time").hide();
            $("tr.shipping").show();
            $(".paymentoption").html('');
            $(".paymentoption").html('You Selected - Enter shipping address');
            var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
            var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
            var phoneUser = $("#phoneUser").val();
            var floorUnit = $("#floorUnit").val();
            var bldgName = $("#bldgName").val();
            var cityList = $("#cityList option:selected").text(); 

            var zipCode = $("#zipCode").val();
            var landRemark = $("#remarkslandinput").val();          
            var saveResidence = $("input[name='saveResidence']:checked").val();
            var residenceName = $("#residenceName").val();
            if(floorUnit == "")
            {errMsg = "* Floor Unit or House No. cannot be left blank!"+'\n';}
            if(bldgName == "")
            {errMsg += "* Bldg Name or House.cannot be left blank!"+'\n';}
            if(zipCode == ""){errMsg += "* Zipcode cannot be left blank!"+'\n';}
            if(saveResidence == "formcheck"){
            if(residenceName == ""){errMsg += "* Residence Name cannot be left blank!";}}
            if(errMsg){alert(errMsg);
            return false;
            }else{
            if(saveResidence == "formcheck"){
                $.post(WCMA_Ajax.ajaxurl, {
                        action               : 'saveNewAddress',
                        id                   : new_id,
                        firstName            : firstName,
                        lastName             : lastName,
                        floorUnit            : floorUnit,
                        bldgName             : bldgName,
                        cityList             : cityList,
                        zipCode              : zipCode,
                        landRemark           : landRemark,
                        residenceName        : residenceName,
                        wc_multiple_addresses: WCMA_Ajax.wc_multiple_addresses
                    }, function (response) {
                            //alert(response);
                        }
                    );
                }

                var remarksdata = $('#remarkslandinput').val();
                var floorUnit =$('#floorUnit').val();
                var bldgName =$('#bldgName').val();
                var cityList =$('#cityList').val();
                var zipCode =$('#zipCode').val();

                $('.ui.sidebar-shipto').sidebar('hide');
                $('.ui.sidebar-checkout').sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'push');
                $('.ui.sidebar-checkout').sidebar('push page');
                $('.woocommerce-shipping-fields .shipping_address').show();
                $("#shipping_first_name").val(firstName);
                $("#shipping_last_name").val(lastName);
                $('#shipping_address_1').val(floorUnit);
                $('#shipping_address_2').val(bldgName);
                $('#landmarkremarks-span').html(remarksdata);
                $('#landmarkremarks').val(remarksdata);
                $('#shipping_postcode').val(zipCode);
                $('#shipping_postcode-span').html(zipCode);
                $('#shipping_city-span').html(cityList);
                $('#shipping_city').val(cityList);
                $("#text-flrnumber").html(floorUnit);
                $("#text-addressname").html(bldgName);
                $("#text-cityaddress").html(cityList);
                $("#text-postalid").html(zipCode);
                $("#billing_phone").val(phoneUser);
                        $("#text-pickdate").html('');
                        $("#text-picktime").html('');
            }
        }else if(radioValue == '2'){
            $("#pickup_date_time").show();
            $(".paymentoption").html('');
            $(".paymentoption").html('You Selected - Pick up from the store');
            pickDate = $('#pick_date').val();
            if(pickDate == ""){
                //alert("please select date");
                $("#pick_date").after("");
                alert("Please select date.");
                return false;                   
            }else{
                $('.ui.sidebar-shipto').sidebar('hide');
                $('.ui.sidebar-checkout').sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'push');
                $('.ui.sidebar-checkout').sidebar('push page');

                pickTime = $('#pick_time').val();
                html = '<div id="pickup_date_time">'+
                            '<b>Pickup Date: '+pickDate+'<br />Pickup Time: '+pickTime+'</b>'+
                            '<input type="hidden" name="h_pick_date" id="h_pick_date" value="'+pickDate+'" />'+
                            '<input type="hidden" name="h_pick_time" id="h_pick_time" value="'+pickTime+'" />'+
                        '</div>';

                var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
                var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
                $( "#pickup_date_time" ).remove();
                $('.woocommerce-shipping-fields').append(html);
                $("#shipping_first_name").val(firstName);
                $("#shipping_last_name").val(lastName);
                $('#shipping_address_1').val('Pickup from Store');
                $('#shipping_address_2').val('Pickup from Store');
                $('#shipping_postcode').val('00000');
                $('#landmarkremarks').html('landmarkremarks');
                $("#text-flrnumber").html('');
                $("#text-addressname").html('');
                $("#text-cityaddress").html('');
                $("#text-postalid").html('For Pickup');     
                $("#text-pickdate").html(pickDate); 
                $("#text-picktime").html(pickTime);
                $("#order_comments").html('Pickup Date: '+pickDate+' Pickup Time: '+pickTime+'');


            }
            $("tr.shipping").hide();
        }else if(radioValue == 'check'){
            console.log('check');
            var noSaved = $("input[name='no-saved-address']:checked").val();
            if(noSaved == "nosaved"){
                alert("You have no address saved yet, edit your profile to My Account sidebar.");
                return false;                   
            } else {
            $('.ui.sidebar-shipto').sidebar('hide');
            $('.ui.sidebar-checkout').sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'push');
            $('.ui.sidebar-checkout').sidebar('push page');

            $('.woocommerce-shipping-fields .shipping_address').show();

            jQuery('input[name*=shipping_alt]').each(function(index){
                    if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')=='checked'){
                        firstName = $("#firstName").val();
                        lastName = $("#lastName").val();
                        address1 = jQuery('#address1',jQuery(this).parent()).html();
                        address2 = jQuery('#address2',jQuery(this).parent()).html();
                        city = jQuery('#city',jQuery(this).parent()).html();
                        var finalcity = city+' City';
                            console.log("city__"+finalcity);
                        postcode = jQuery('#postcode',jQuery(this).parent()).html();

                        $('#shipping_first_name').val(firstName);
                        $('#shipping_last_name').val(lastName);
                        $('#shipping_address_1').val(address1);
                        $('#shipping_address_2').val(address2);
                        $("#text-flrnumber").html(address1);
                        $("#text-addressname").html(address2);
                        $("#text-pickdate").html('');
                        $("#text-picktime").html('');

                        var myOptions = {'Makati City' : 'Makati City', 'Taguig City' : 'Taguig City'};
                        var mySelect = $('#shipping_city');
                        $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
                            mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
                        });
                        $('#shipping_city').val(finalcity);
                        $("#text-cityaddress").html(finalcity);
                        $('#shipping_postcode').val(postcode);
                        $("#text-postalid").html(postcode);
                    }

            });
            }

        }
        else{
            $(".paymentoption").html('');
            $(".paymentoption").html('enter or select address');
            alert('Please select a shipping method.');
            return false;
        }

    });
```